# Android Studio and Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, android-studio

When I open Android Studio for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS a file is modified: `/home/davide/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/.idea/workspace.xml Does not match`
is this a normal thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, is a normal thing. Android Studio open workspace.xml file on startup.